# ORA-01722 error message

Tags: php, oracle

I'm trying to input some data into oracle tables and i'm receiving error code  ORA-01722. I believe its because of the Trader ID which is a number but its saying it can't convert a string to a number. Code below.

Form

```
<form method="post" action="recipesql.php" >
      <table align="center">
<tr>
            <td align="right">Recipe Name:</td>
            <td align="left"><input type="text" name="RecipeName"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td align="right">Media Type:</td>
            <td align="left"><input type="text" name="MediaType"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td align="right">Recipe:</td>
            <td align="left"><input type="text" name="Recipe" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td align="right">Video Link (e.g /embed/12345):</td>
            <td align="left"><input type="text" name="Link"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td align="right">Trader ID:</td>
            <td align="left"><input type="number" name="TraderID"></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">

   </form>
```

PHP

```
//include connection
include ('PHP/connection.php');
//has form been submitted?
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $RecipeName=$_POST['Name'];
    $MediaType=$_POST['MediaType'];
    $Recipe=$_POST['Recipe'];
    $Link=$_POST['Video_Link'];
    $TraderID=$_POST['Trader_ID'];
//Insert data
$query = "INSERT INTO MEDIA
(Media_Id, Name, MediaType, Recipe, Video_Link, Trader_ID)
VALUES
('MEDIA_seq.nextval','$RecipeName','$MediaType','$Recipe','$Link','$TraderID')";

$runquery = oci_parse($connection,$query);
oci_execute($runquery);
} 
//to check if the if statement is working
else
{
    echo "Error";
}
```

Error code Warning: oci_execute() [function.oci-execute]: ORA-01722: invalid number in recipesql.php on line 19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think it should be:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO MEDIA (Media_Id, Name, MediaType, Recipe, Video_Link, Trader_ID) 
VALUES (MEDIA_seq.nextval,'$RecipeName','$MediaType','$Recipe','$Link','$TraderID')";
```

i.e. `MEDIA_seq.nextval` not enclosed in `''`. Otherwise it is interpreted as a `VARCHAR2` and inserting it into a `NUMBER` column causes an `ORA-01722`.